# How do I go to line in code where page fault exception occurs (in VS 2005)?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception

I am running a release version of an executable (built with Visual Studio 2005) in a production environment.  We are getting a page fault exception and the dump gives an address.  How do I translate this address to the line of code within Visual Studio 2005?  Do I need to be running a Debug build?

Comment: What about this issue? Do you get any latest information about this issue in your side?

Answer (score 0):

What I know is that if we want to really get the line number which threw the Exception, we need to have the full dump file like the matched PDB file or others.

You can also use the Windbg tool and command line:

Reference:

[is it possible to get the line from which the exception was thrown from a dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823066/is-it-possible-to-get-the-line-from-which-the-exception-was-thrown-from-a-dump)

[Windows/C++: Is it possible to find the line of code where exception was thrown having "Exception Offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528776/windows-c-is-it-possible-to-find-the-line-of-code-where-exception-was-thrown)

Note: Since VS 2005 is really old version, we also have no this Environment now, if possible, maybe you could use higher VS version like VS2015/VS2017.